# Regarding data types

Tags: python, types

I have started programming recently and I got confused when I learnt about data types. Why do we have/need datatypes?
Also languages like Python don't have data types making themm much simpler to learn. Why do languages like C or C++ have datatypes then?

Comment: You are wrong, python has data types. Please read [the doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datatypes.html)

Comment: Python has data types. Without them, how would you differentiate between `'1'`, `1.0` and `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_type) of a variable determines what kind of data it can store and what possible values it may take. It also help in determining what type of operations can be performed on the variable.
It is wrong to say that Python doesn't have datatypes. Even in Python every value has a datatype, but you don’t always need to declare the datatype of the variables. Based on each variable’s original assignment, Python figures out what type it is and keeps track of that internally.

Answer (score 0):

There is an important distinction of data types for **variables** (which only statically typed languages have, the respective statements are called declarations and help to  determine and allocate the correct amount of memory at fixed addresses) and data types of **values**, which are much more common. Data types for variables help the compiler to detect incompatible assignments. As a side benefit of this effort for the developer (unnecessary for dynamically typed languages) the compiler may issue warnings for variables never used, detect attempts to use uninitialized variables etc.

Answer (score 0):

Data types impose abstract structure on data. This abstraction allows us to work with data through simpler interfaces, or to use more efficient a algorithms for manipulating data.

Data types (structures) are the bread and butter of computer science.

Languages generally have built-in support for a few common data types (such as arrays, lists, associative arrays), and then vary in how well they support *user defined data types*.